# How to disable input when overlay is shown

Tags: c#, input, overlay

I'm doing external game overlay and I want it to have menu, but I have no idea how to disable input on the game and focus just on overlay. Since game is protected by EAC I can't inject any code. Is there any way I could solve this issue ? For overlay I'm using GameOverlay.Net library. Thanks in advance.
P.s. I'm not creating a cheat, just utility tool for the game, which is allowed by this game company.

Comment: What game is this for and the intended use for the overlay?

Comment: It's for Albion Online. It will be a utility tool, like a helper. So far I've made xp calculator, gained silver counter.